# jQuery Quicksand + Captify (Rollover Script)

Tags: javascript, jquery, rollover, quicksand

so I have a little issue with my jQuery Captify (Caption on image rollovers) and Quicksand (Image filtering system) not working so well together. When the page loads, my Captify works well when I roll my mouse over the images, however as soon as I click a link to filter my thumbnails, the captify script stops working.

I tried to call the captify script every x seconds, but I'm either not doing it correctly or it's just not the right solution. Can anyone help me out? The site can be found at http://www.galaxyturbo.net/new/index.php

If you have Firebug or similar developer tools like in Google Chrome, you can take a look at my code from there, I just didn't want to perhaps spam this page. Thanks SO much in advance if you can help me out here, I'm really desperate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would say we both need to learn more JavaScript, but I had the same problem, and here is how you make it work :

What you need to do is RECALL THE CAPTIFY FUNCTION AFTER THE QUICKSAND CLONNING !
so look for the JS code for quicksand, look for :

```
    $holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
        duration: 800,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
    });
    return false;
```

**that should look like this :**

```
    $holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
        duration: 800,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
    },
    // RECALL CAPTIFY  ===============================
       function() { $('img.captify').captify({
        speedOver: 'fast',
        speedOut: 'normal',
        hideDelay: 500,
        animation: 'slide',
        prefix: '',
        opacity: '0.7',
        className: 'caption-bottom',
        position: 'bottom',
        spanWidth: '100%'
        });
       }
    // RECALL CAPTIFY  ==============================
    );
    return false;
```

hope that helps !
also, you will have to do the same with other scripts, like LightBox or PrettyPhoto .

Comment: Thank you very much for your post! I had to go back and change my quicksand structure completely to try and support your answer, and sure enough it worked! Much love and respect buddy, if I could vote your post up I would but it turns out I need more reputation or something (StackOverflow newbie).

Comment: you know... I gave up on Captify ... seems like coding my own captions works better and does not make the website work slow ...